# Copyright Key and Value Not in info.plist

Tags: ios, app-store, copyright-display

I am preparing my first app for submission to the App Store, in Apple's documentation they say to:

> Make sure that your information property list file contains a valid value for the Copyright key.

And then show in a picture what they are talking about which can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXxS9.png

However, my info.plist does not contain a copyright Key or Value.  How do I get one in there, is it even really necessary to have this? Is there a chance apple will reject my app without this?

Comment: You just click on the "Information Property List" row/column and you will be able to create a new row!

Comment: @MartinH Thanks, that worked!  It was a dumb question so I understand the down votes, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome. You were lucky you only got one down vote ;-)

Comment: This seems like a valid question, no need to down vote.  Someone should answer it, or we can close it if there is a dupe.

Answer (score 5):

Apple Documentation indicates this is needed for Mac apps, but implies thereby that it's not needed for iOS apps.

See: Setting the Copyright Key (Mac) section in:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html

...

NSHumanReadableCopyright (String - macOS). This key contains a string with the copyright notice for the bundle; for example, © 2016, My Company. You can load this string and display it in an About dialog box. The system uses this string in the app’s Info window in Finder.